# To create shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script

I want to create a script to check size of all the files present under particular folder,  and if size of any file present under a folder cross 500mb it would trigger a mail to me specifying the file name which size have cross above 500mb..

Answer (score 3):

You're not asking any question, just telling us what you're planning to do. But here's what you're probably looking for:

```
find /path -size +500M -ls | mail -s "large file list" youraddress@example.com
```

Comment: I wonder if you're "feeding the trolls" by rewarding a rather poor question... +1 for you though